# "Скажи спасибо"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли брать в кавычки слово "спасибо" в предложениях подобного рода: "Скажи спасибо, что тебя это не коснулось!"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет. "Спасибо" здесь не означает прямую речь, а является синонимом слову "благодарность". "Скажи спасибо" = "Выскажи благодарность".