# Заключать ли в кавычки слово нет?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки

Нужно ли заключать в кавычки слово *нет* в следующем предложении?

*Псевдорегулированию – твердое нет!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Псевдорегулированию** – **твердое** (слово) **нет!**

В  предложении такой структуры кавычки лучше не ставить. ***Нет*** здесь является частицей со значением отрицания. Выражение  (*твердое нет*) имеет оттенок устойчивости, но написание пока неустоявшееся.

В Сети встречаются оба варианта, в литературных произведениях  ― тоже, хотя там чаще используется вариант с кавычками.

Ему надо было услышать либо **твёрдое «да», либо твёрдое «нет»**. [Алексей Иванов (Алексей Маврин). Псоглавцы. Гл. 21-39 (2011)]

Как будто я много лет подряд умолял его пошарить там, и вот сегодня, он, наконец, сказал мне **свое твердое нет.** [Мариам Петросян. Дом, в котором... (2009)]

Answer (score 0):

Недавно был подобный вопрос по поводу *спасибо*. Думаю, здесь можно применить тот же подход. *Нет* употреблено не дословно, а в смысле некоего отрицания, поэтому нет кавычек.
[Кавычится ли такое название журнала? А слово "спасибо"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/436577/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b6%d1%83%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%90-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%be/436593#436593)
А вот еще: ["Скажи спасибо"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/9849/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%be)